# using input as both an array and a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I feel like there is a simple solution to this but I am  kinda new.

```
stat_input= input("Hello Mr. Jenner, what are you interested in tracking today?")
```

I use an input like this which later is used to call upon data and uses that data to calculate statistics and produce histogram charts / normal distributions.

It works quite nicely. Here are some examples where it is used.

```
cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM statdata'.format(stat_input))
np.array(stat_input).astype(np.float)

sigma = math.sqrt(np.var(stat_input))
```

So if I type `threemonthdata` it will pull the array of data from my database and use it . Its great.  However, I have one small problem

I understand that `threemonthdata` refers to an array. Since I am creating charts, I want to use the input as the title so the chart title identifies what data I am drawing and using (as a reference in the future)

```
ax.set_title('stat_input')
```

This doesn't work

```
ax.set_title(' + stat_input + ')
```

Nor does this. I want the title to say `Threemonthdata`. But if I input `twomonthdata` I want it to say `twomonthdata` and not give me the array of numbers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never played with psycopg's [`cursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html) class. But, from what I can read, it appears that this one does the job for you of turning  your string in place into a list whose name is the same as the referring string.

Thus what about defining another viariable to store the string before it is overriden ? As follows

```
stat_input_title = stat_input.capitalize()
cur.execute('SELECT {} FROM statdata'.format(stat_input))
```

Henceforth, `stat_input_title` and `stat_input` can be used together withouh conflicting.

```
ax.set_title(stat_input_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you are facing is that you are passing the `set_title()` a string `'stat_input'`, and not the variable `stat_input`.  You likely simply need to use:

```
ax.set_title(stat_input)
```

Comment: You are right, but how could `math.sqrt(np.var(stat_input))` works in this case ? `stat_input` is an array since the OP says : "*I want the title [...] not give me the array of numbers.*" Also, it appears that the OP thinks that by doing `'stat_input'`, he will get as string the original name of the numpy array. Actually, as if he were coding in stata, handling local macros.